# Josephus game using java

Tags: java

I am currently having problems with my Josephus code.

The purpose of the code is to ask a user for 3 integers and then execute.

For some sequence of numbers it works perfectly while other sequences it produces the wrong output. For example if I enter 7(size), 1(holder) 3(pass). I get the last integer as 3 when it is suppose to be 2. I am also having an issue with the size not starting at 1.

For Example if I define my size as 7, it is suppose to start at 1.2.3... but instead starts at 8.2.4..

I believe the problem lies with the deleteList method. Since I notice that when the program reaches the sequence where the list is (2,3,5,7), it does not delete properly. I can't figure why it is deleting 3 instead of 5.

```
       public void deleteList(int holder, int pass, int listSize){// method to determine which number gets deleted

          while(listSize!= 1){

          Link current = find(holder, listSize);

          Link previous = first;


          for(int i = 1; i < pass; i++){
             current = current.next;

          }

          previous = current;     

          current = current.next;


          if(current == first){
                  first = first.next;

          }
          else{

             previous.next = current.next;


          }
          holder = current.next.iData;
          displayList(--listSize);
          }
       }
```

Comment: You should narrow down the issue, and post a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Please explain what "Josephus' Game" is in your question, post your full code.